# SQL Update row with data from other flat table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have two tables: Assets and Values

Assets

```
unid|name|memory|brand|type|status|processor|supplier|hostname|building|datebought|user
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
D7930C14-3196-49DA-BAC9-9D03F5FA9E8F|Object1|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null
2FFA7056-4C9B-4375-B14F-4A927A55BA0C|Object2|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null
```

Values

```
assetid|fieldname|textvalue
---------------------------
D7930C14-3196-49DA-BAC9-9D03F5FA9E8F|memory|16
D7930C14-3196-49DA-BAC9-9D03F5FA9E8F|brand|09e9a777-3899-48ed-a1e8-d50e4469e157
D7930C14-3196-49DA-BAC9-9D03F5FA9E8F|type|0261f606-1253-41d3-9b17-4464763bb187
D7930C14-3196-49DA-BAC9-9D03F5FA9E8F|status|4dde3e20-da2d-4e1e-a9d4-51039b74e6ca
2FFA7056-4C9B-4375-B14F-4A927A55BA0C|datebought|2017-11-20T23:00:00.000
D7930C14-3196-49DA-BAC9-9D03F5FA9E8F|processor|0536f0c2-46f3-4245-b8e8-41e092e03e44
2FFA7056-4C9B-4375-B14F-4A927A55BA0C|type|7380b254-6b40-42b8-9584-a16e6f14409e
D7930C14-3196-49DA-BAC9-9D03F5FA9E8F|supplier|c3ee564a-3a46-546f-82e4-7b42f21ec841
D7930C14-3196-49DA-BAC9-9D03F5FA9E8F|hostname|object1
D7930C14-3196-49DA-BAC9-9D03F5FA9E8F|building|0536f0c2-46f3-9995-b8e8-41e092e03e44
D7930C14-3196-49DA-BAC9-9D03F5FA9E8F|datebought|2017-06-14T22:00:00.000
D7930C14-3196-49DA-BAC9-9D03F5FA9E8F|user|ac2d9a93-f09c-5d13-bd78-7e3ba2a749e6
2FFA7056-4C9B-4375-B14F-4A927A55BA0C|brand|09e9a777-3899-48ed-a1e8-d50e4469e157
2FFA7056-4C9B-4375-B14F-4A927A55BA0C|supplier|c3ee564a-3a46-546f-82e4-7b42f21ec841
2FFA7056-4C9B-4375-B14F-4A927A55BA0C|status|4dde3e20-da2d-4e1e-a9d4-51039b74e6ca
```

As you see table Assets has a lot of null values in its rows. That null values need to be filled with the values from the table Values.

It's difficult for me, because every value in the table Value is in a seperate row. So multiple rows from Values need to be updated into columns in a single row in Assets.

The relation between the two tables is
Assets.unid = Values.assetid

I tried using a pivot like below, but I still don't know how to update the data to the corresponding row.

```
select "memory", "brand", "type", "status", "processor", "supplier", "hostname", "building", "datebought", "user"
from
(
  select cast(textvalue as varchar(max)) as textvalue, fieldname
  from am_value
) d
pivot
(
  max(textvalue)
  for fieldname in ("memory", "brand", "type", "status", "processor", "supplier", "hostname", "building", "datebought", "user" )
) piv
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi first we will form pivoted resultset with the following query

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(fieldname) 
                    from Values
                    GROUP BY fieldname 
                    order by 1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT assetid ,' + @cols + ' into #temp from 
             (
                select *
                from values
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(textvalue)
                for COL in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

now you can update your table with the values in temp#